# Spring Integration resequencer does not release the last group of messages

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow messageFlow(JdbcMessageStore groupMessageStore, TransactionSynchronizationFactory syncFactory, TaskExecutor te, ThreadPoolTaskScheduler ts, RealTimeProcessor processor) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("inputChannel")
                .handle(processor, "handleInputMessage", consumer -> consumer
                        .taskScheduler(ts)
                        .poller(poller -> poller
                                .fixedDelay(pollerFixedDelay)
                                .receiveTimeout(pollerReceiveTimeout)
                                .maxMessagesPerPoll(pollerMaxMessagesPerPoll)
                                .taskExecutor(te)
                                .transactional()
                                .transactionSynchronizationFactory(syncFactory)))
                .resequence(s -> s.messageStore(groupMessageStore)
                        .releaseStrategy(new TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy(50, 30000)))
                .channel("sendingChannel")
                .handle(processor, "sendMessage")
                .get();
    }
```

If I send a single batch of e.g. 100 messages to the `inputChannel` it works as expected until there are no messages in the `inputChannel`. After the `inputChannel` becomes empty it also stops processing for messages that were waiting for sequencing. As a result there are always a couple of messages left in the `groupMessageStore` even after the set release timeout.

I'm guessing it's because the poller is configured only for the `inputChannel` and if there are no messages in there it will never get to the sequencer (so will never call `canRelease` on the release strategy).
But if I try adding a separate poller for the resequencer I get the following error `A poller should not be specified for endpoint since channel x is a SubscribableChannel (not pollable).`

Is there a different way to configure it so that the last group of messages is always released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release strategy is passive and needs something to trigger it to be called.

Add `.groupTimeout(...)` to release the partial sequence after the specified time elapses.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67993972Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So67993972Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67993972Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(MessageGroupStore mgs) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.direct("input"))
                .resequence(e -> e.messageStore(mgs)
                                    .groupTimeout(5_000)
                                    .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                                    .releaseStrategy(new TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy(50, 2000)))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("output"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageGroupStore mgs() {
        return new SimpleMessageStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel input, QueueChannel output, MessageGroupStore mgs) {
        return args -> {
            MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate(input);
            log.info("Sending");
            template.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                    .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID, "bar")
                    .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER, 2)
                    .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_SIZE, 2)
                    .build());
            log.info(output.receive(10_000).toString());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            log.info(mgs.getMessagesForGroup("bar").toString());
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! The timeout worked and those remaining messages got sent however they have not been removed from the ```groupMessageStore```. Should they be released manually?

Comment: They are removed, but after the output is sent; so if you check too soon, they will still be there; if you remove the `Thread.sleep()` in the example I added to my answer, the message is still there but with the sleep, it is gone.

Comment: Just to be clear, the remove is done under a lock so there is no danger if a new message arrives for that group while we are timing out the group. If the query was done under the same lock, the sleep would not be needed.